# Como configurar uma Activity para ocupar todo o espaço da tela?

Tags: android

Quero esconder até a barra de notificações!!

Answer (score 2):

Para ocupar toda tela você tem duas opções:

## 1 - Por Tema

Basta usar/herdar o tema `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`. Lembrando que você não terá o `ActionBar`, podendo usar o `Toolbar` para suprir essa falta.

## 2 - Programaticamente

Basta fazer a requisição da remoção do título e setar as *flag's* de **FullScreen** a `Window`:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Lembrando que é preciso executar esse trecho depois da chamada ao `super.onCreate` e antes do `setContentView`. Caso contrário irá falhar devido a presença de conteúdo.

Acredito que a primeiração opção seja mais elegante, pode ser mais suave que a segunda.